# Python algorithm to scan a rectangular area by a drone and calculate the flying time

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a course project where I need to write a python algorithm to do the following steps:

1- Take the camera angle, flyings height and sped for the user.

2- Take x and y (represents longitude and altitude) from the user.

3- Calculate the area of the rectangle the drone needs to scan.

4- Divide the area into columns based on the camera angle.

5- Make the drone start from the middle of the first column from top then goes to bottom, then moves half of the next column's width and goes from bottom to top. the repeat till the whole area covered.

6- calculate distance then flying time.

The first 4 steps are straight forward and i added them to clarify the task details.

The algorithm required in the 5th step and then how to calculate the flying time is what I need help at.

I'm new to algorithm writing and coding in python in general, can anyone help on how I can write the algorithm required in step 5

I added the code I wrote to getting the total distance. I keep getting the distance = 0. plus I don't think the distance of the path is correctly calculated (please see the attached screenshot to shows the path)

```
def distance(height, angle, speed, x1, y1, x2, y2):
xc = (x1 + x2)/2  
yc = (y1 + y2)/2
xd = (x1 - x2)/2
yd = (y1 - y2)/2

#Third corner
x3 = xc - yd  
y3 = yc + xd

#Fourth corner
x4 = xc + yd
y4 = yc - xd

#width and heigth of the rectangle
width = x2 - x1
length= y2 - y1

#calculating a single column width
column_w = (math.sin(angle/2) * height) * 2

total_columns = int(width / column_w)
total_distance= 0

for i in range(total_columns):
    total_distance = total_distance + length
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        print("drone movement: down, right, up")
    else:
        print("drone movement: up, right, down")
print(total_distance)
print(legnth)
```

#To get the inputs from the user

```
height = int(input("Enter height:"))
angle = int(input("Enter angle:"))
speed = int(input("Enter speed:"))
x1 = int(input("Enter x1:"))
y1 = int(input("Enter y1:"))
x2 = int(input("Enter x2:"))
y2 = int(input("Enter y2:"))

distance(height, angle, speed, x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close as needs details/clarity. It's for a course project, but have you been taught anything relevant to your homework that you can use as reference? Do you even struggle with the first 3 steps? I don't understand exactly what you're supposed to do in step 4. The rest also sound straightforward. Where do you face any problems? Asking for ideas/resources is consider off topic. You should narrow down your problem to one issue, because at the moment I count 6 questions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just edited the question, the 5th step is where I need help in how I can write such as algorithm that scan/map a rectangular area from top to bottom then from from bottom to top till cover the whole area that is already divided to columns.

Comment: Can you calculate the distance on paper? Then time is distance divided by speed. When you have the exact formula, you can write a Python program that will calculate it for you from input variables. Or do you need to write a program to actually control the drone?

Comment: The distance will depends on two values entered by the user (the area of the rectangle  and the drone's camera angle that will divide the rectangle into a number of columns) 
What I need is how to calculate the distance that the drone flies to cover all the area.
as it flies from top to bottom, then moves to the next column and flies from bottom to top and so on.

Comment: Then you know the distance from top to bottom of the rectangle and the width between two "lanes". So the total distance travelled is how many times you have to travel top->bottom (or vice versa) + how many times you have to travel laterally times the width.

Comment: Try drawing a diagram looking at the plane from the side with the apex of a triangle representing the camera's view at the plane and the base of the triangle on the ground. You know the angle of the FOV from the user and the height above ground, then think back to your rusty old maths teacher and trigonometry and formula for tangents.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more to do as a formula rather than an "algorithm".

Your resulting flight path is a series of "S"s starting top left, down, U-turn, back up, U-turn, down and so on and so forth.
From what you've written in step #5, when the drone does a U-turn it goes sideways half the width of a column.

The total "hight" is given by the `y` input, so `h1` is similar to that (minus some for camera angle etc).
The total width of the field is given by the `x` input (I think).
Assuming we have `n` columns in it with width `w1`, we get the number of U-turns:
Each one moves `w1/2` sideways and so coverage is (for `m` sideways moves):
`1 + m * (w1/2) = n * w1`.
This results in `m = 2n - 1` (after rounding up) U-turns.
Works out you'll need `2n * h1` (up/down flights - maybe `2n-1` for odd/even cases) + `(2n-1) * w1` sideway fligths.

For a complete path:

```
direction = 'down'
nextUTurn = 'left'
columnsNeeded = n
for (columnIndex of columnsNeeded) {
  print(direction)
  print('U-Turn ' + nextUTurn)
  direction = getOther(direction)
  nextUTurn = getOther(nextUTurn)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not clear. can you elaborate by writing the algorithm/loops to get distance with the u-turns?

Comment: If you're looking to get the total distance, it's just an equation.

Comment: I still don't see how this will calculate the distance of the path.
Please see the the code I added in the question body and tell me your opinion/correction.
Thank you

Comment: @DerekWilliams The pseudo code I wrote would print out the entire path. Hence you could also print the distances and/or sum them

Comment: @DerekWilliams - every time the pseudo-code prints something - print also the distance and have a variable summing up the total.